# Capture an event before shifting between tabs

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I am writing a firefox addon for which I need to capture any event (if I can) that is triggered just before moving out from one tab to another. I tried onLocationChange method in the ProgressListener, but that captures the event only after the user has landed to the second tab. I need an event that can capture this activity just before the user is about to move out from one tab to another.

Any suggestions?

Kapil

Answer (score 1):

TabSelect will fire after the tab has been selected, so that won't work.

I have this same problem, only I'd like to trigger an event before a tab opens, so as to stop it opening.

Have you tried setting an onclick event on the tabs in the tab bar?

Comment: A tab can be opened by various events - not just clicking the new-tab button. For example, you could click a link in a page and open in a new tab also. I also posted the same question of forums.mozillazine website and someone replied that this is not possible - I am not sure why such a hook is not designed.

Comment: Here is the thread on mozillazie http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=2093651

Answer (score 0):

That would be TabSelect.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser