# Mozila Firefox: Capturing an event right before tab change

Tags: tabs, firefox-addon

I'm looking for an event that can be fired just right before changing a tab?
I have already seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898290/capture-an-event-before-shifting-between-tabs), and I have also looked into the tabSelect event in the firefox extension, but I couldn't find any event that can be fired just before the tab change.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no such event.

However you can watch, with a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), the `type` attribute of selected tab's `browser` element (`gBrowser.mCurrentBrowser`). When it changes from `content-primary` to `content-targetable` it's a signal that a tab switch is in progress.

Answer (score 2):

As paa already noted, there is no event that happens before a tab is selected. What you can use are tricks, e.g. the [`Object.watch()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch) (yes, using it isn't exactly recommended). It allows you to listen to changes of the `gBrowser.tabContainer.selectedIndex` property (the setter of this property is where the `select` event is being fired):

```js
gBrowser.tabContainer.watch("selectedIndex", function(prop, oldval, newval)
{
  // New tab being selected, do something here!
  return newval;
});
```

The advantage of this approach: by returning `oldval` from the handler you can prevent the selection from taking place.